# Extending Data Object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extending a data object in TypeScript, by adding some new fields. While I guess it's a quite common pattern in JavaScript, I can't make it be able to compile, without making `bar` as optional in the snippet as below.

I'm wondering is there any way to avoid making `bar` optional. 
Any suggestion would be welcome, thank you.

```
interface BaseDataObject {
    foo: string;
}

interface ExtendedDataObject extends BaseDataObject {
    bar?: string;
}

function extendData(input : BaseDataObject) : ExtendedDataObject {
    var output : ExtendedDataObject = input;
    output.bar = input.foo + ' some suffix';
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by compile-time casting `input` to `ExtendedDataObject` instead of just assigning it to `output`:

```
interface ExtendedDataObject extends BaseDataObject {
    bar: string;
}

function extendData(input : BaseDataObject) : ExtendedDataObject {
    var output = input as ExtendedDataObject;
    output.bar = input.foo + ' some suffix';
    return output;
}
```

This type of cast is officially called [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) and it tells the compiler to trust you that the object can be treated as the type you indicate.

Comment: It seems like this is the only way to avoid it.

Comment: It works, thanks. And I assume the compiling time check for missing fields is bypassed, right?

Comment: @Haocheng Right, this is officially called a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) and it tells the compiler to trust you that the object can be treated as the type you indicate.